# How to create an Evernote note with Windows Phone 7 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, evernote

I've done the oAuth part without any problems.  I now have the user token, but can't seem to figure out how to call the WebService call CreateNote to create a new note, any samples out there using for Silverlight/WP7 development?  I tried adding the web service reference but that fails.  The sample code the SDK has is only for C# and requires sockets I believe.

I've setup an account and am using the URI: http://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note

thanks,
Sam

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

we've got a beta version of our API client bindings for Silverlight that I can share with you; shoot me an email at seth at evernote dot com.

Comment: hi seth. now we are got same problem with Evernote Windows Phone API. Cloud u please send me Beta Version API Docuemnt to [Eamil:]chenkaiHome@live.cn   Thanks